# Как отформатировать (перебрать) csv под такой шаблон?

Tags: excel, csv

Коллеги, всем привет!
Подскажите как решить задачу.

Есть такой csv файл

name    |param  |   option
xCsw    |qw,rt,we   |   12,43,65

И уже с него хотелось бы получить на выходе

name    | qw    | rt    | we
xCsw    |12 |43 |65

Тоесть "нечто" должно брать данные с ячейки и превращать их в колонки. Может быть существует какой-то конструктор CSV?

Подскажите на что обратить внимание.
Спасибо.

Comment: Это просто задание для универа или реальный проект?

Comment: "|"  - это же не разделитель столбцов для *Excel*, данные на листе -
 а одной ячейке? Открыть в *Excel*, *Текст_по_столбцам*, разделитель "|". Переставить столбцы. Это если вручную. Макросом: загрузить данные в массив, обработать, выгрузить на лист, преобразовать в *.csv*

Comment: Естественно разделитель ";", слэш для наглядности.

Comment: Отсюда же этого не видно ). В этом случае проще, не нужно разделять, данные сами станут по столбцам. В остальном - см. предыдущее сообщение.